# Best way to publish links to documentation in Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to make my Jenkins builds 1 stop shopping for everyone to make it easy for QA and for on-boarding never team members.  Be they business, QA, DEV, etc...

I currently use HTML reports to publish links to various documents about how to deploy a build, how to test a build, design docs, etc...

Unfortunately, many of our builds are 1-2 gigs in size.  For each HTML report you publish, that plugin copies the build repo into a report folder under html reports.

So for a product that has a build usage of 1.7 gigs...  When I publish 21 reports, it uses and additional 22 gigs of disk space...  That is per build, if you keep 10 builds and you set save old reports, I've turned that off, but still the disk space usage is a problem...

Then multiply that by 20 different jobs..  Well, suddenly disk space becomes a serious problem.

So... How to publish external link, HTML reports, etc...  That doesn't use so much extra space?

We have tried to use the description before, had problems with making that readable, but it worked for the static links with out disk space problems. For the html report we do generate in the build, that did not work in initial efforts.  If that really is the best option, we can give that a go again.

Comment: You already mentioned it in a comment below, but just to point that out: If you use the HTML Publisher plugin, that plugin will archive the directory you configure. So provide it with a subfolder containing only the HTML files. Here are the docs: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of solutions come to mind.

1. Create and deploy a single page that has links to where the other documentation can be found.
2. Check out the [Sidebar-Link Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin).  It allows you to put links in the left menu bar (sidebar).

Comment: Solves all but one of problems. :)  Perhaps you know the key to the last issue... My build generates an HTML file, I am failing to figure out how to link to it.  All of my other links were already published under various wikis, share point servers, etc...  The html page that is generate is not under any web page and the HTML report plugin would publish them, but clone the entire build directory at the same time.  I just need what ever report in the Jenkins repository to be published.

Comment: @Shire Try the [Html Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin).  It might solve the last bit.

Comment: The HTML Publisher Plugin is the problem I am trying to solve. :(  It copies the entire build folder tree for each link you provide it.

Comment: Found a solution.  Put the report in a sub folder and configure the html publisher to use that folder and then it only copies that subfolder.